# itextsharp tutorials for vb.net express 2008?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pdf

anyone know if these are available?

Comment: I've no idea, but if no one has an answer, you'll be able to find out on the iText mailing list. https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/itext-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this:

[iText.NET VB Examples](http://www.ujihara.jp/iTextdotNET/en/examplesvb.html)

is the closest you're likely to find in VB.NET.

There's also this:
[using iTextSharp. NET Form in PDF output](http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fcodezine.jp%2Farticle%2Fdetail%2F462&sl=ja&tl=en&hl=en&ie=UTF-8)

which isn't a complete tutorial, but does give an overview of using iTextSharp in VB.NET, although I'm not sure how useful that link will be to you since the site is originally in Japanese.  (The link I've provided uses Google Translate to translate most of the text to English).